# Open and close GUI in for loop

Tags: matlab, user-interface

Why does the following work perfectly fine if I step through using the debugger, but produces an error on the second run when run on its own?

```
for i = 1:2  
   clear f;
   cftool; //Call fitting toolbox GUI
   drawnow;
   f = findall(0,'Type','Figure');
   waitfor(f(1));
end
```

Edit: introducing pause(0.1) after the waitfor(f(1)) solves the problem, but conceptually makes no difference to me, the loop should stop anyway after waitfor, shouldn't it?

Comment: what's the error? Maybe its due to waitfor(f(1)) being resumed only when f is deleted, so on the 2nd run there is no f to clear?

Comment: so waitfor() doesn't actually does what I would like it to do. How can I stop the loop from continuing after the waitfor() without doing anything silly like pause()?

Comment: putting a small pause like pause(0.1) helps, but I don't see why it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
for i = 1:2 
   if exist('f','var')==1 
      clear f;
   end
   cftool; //Call fitting toolbox GUI
   drawnow;
   f = findall(0,'Type','Figure');
   waitfor(f(1));
end
```

Comment: Doesn't run through the second iteration for me

Comment: Same as before, Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Comment: Does the error message point to the line `waitfor(f(1))`? If so, add a `size(f)` between the lines `f = ...` and `waitfor(f(1))` to check that `f(1)` does actually exists.

Comment: it does exist as an empty object, which causes the index error, but that doesn't help me, cause I would like to know what the difference is, between going line by line in debugging mode or running it normally.

Comment: Well, at least you know where the error comes from. Have you tried running the code line by line without using the for loop and without using the debugger. When you get to the error, you can experiment and try to find out why `f` is empty.

Comment: Yup, tried it all, must be some hidden feature I don't quite understand, anyway, I'll stick to the workaround using pause()... Cheers